# Print Script with syntax highlighting R-Studio

Tags: r, printing, syntax-highlighting, rstudio

After finishing statistical analysis in R I always like to print out the script since it gives a good overview and one can adjust eventual errors. I like the syntax highlighting in R-Studio because it facilitates reading and fast understanding within huge lines of code. So is there anyway I can print out the text with the highlighting I am used to see in the editor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print with syntax color in R-Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789355/print-with-syntax-color-in-r-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `knitr` to produce a pdf (or some other output).