# Print with syntax color in R-Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

In R I always like to print out the script since it gives a good overview and one can adjust eventual errors. I like the syntax highlighting in R-Studio because it facilitates reading and fast comprehension of code.

Is there a way to print out the text with the highlighting I see in the editor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

RStudio will not print in colour, but it's easy to save the code as a PDF; in this case the syntax format is preserved. My favourite package is knitr.

```
library(knitr) 
stitch("file_name.R")
```

The default output is PDF/Markup in .tex. If you prefer not to typeset, running the below will export as .html

```
stitch(script="file_name.R", system.file("misc", "knitr-template.Rhtml", package="knitr"))
```

Comment: this has been modified to `stitch(script="file_name.R")` note `script` rather than `file`

Comment: This probably is the best solution so far, but The problem is that it runs the code. My code is very very very time consuming to run and I just want the syntax highlighting of my 3k lines of code. any solution for that?

Answer (score 21):

Its not an R-Studio solution, but [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) will print R source with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

## Brief explanation

The reason this is an answer to this question in because of the last line of the question:

> Is there a way to print out the text with the highlighting I see in
>   the editor?

so we are not limited to only and only using Rstudio software here.

After exploring the awesome answer by @rrg and realizing that it runs the code line by line, I wrote a comment below his answer and continued googling. My problem is that the code I wrote is so large and so time consuming to run that running it for the sake of having a syntax highlighted version is not feasible.

Most of the solution out there online involves having notepad++ which is a Windows application and I'm a dedicated Linux user, so I searched for a way I can do this in Linux (and possibly Mac)

## The way I solved it:

Inspired by [a blog post](http://lordamit.blogspot.fi/2010/11/export-your-source-code-in-html-format.html), I used the famous and beloved Vim to convert R to syntax highlighted HTML and then because you can open HTML in your browser, you can what ever you want with it (print, screenshot, etc.)

1. Activate synax highlighting in Vim:

   - open terminal
   - then open the vim config file by typing `vim ~/.vimrc`
   - press <kbd>i</kbd> from keyboard to go to "insert mode"
   - go to the end of the file using arrow keys on your keyboard
   - type `syntax on` at the end of the file
   - now you need to save and exit. For this you need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> button from keyboard to come out of "insert mode" and then type `:x` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and close the file.
   - if you want to change the color scheme of the syntax highlighting, visit the bottom part of [this website](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644480/enabling-vi-syntax-colors)
2. From terminal open your file with Vim:

   ```
   vim YOUR_FILE_PATH
   ```
3. Having you R code open in vim, you can turn on the line numbers if you like by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then write `:set number` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. For converting R to HTML, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to make sure you are not in "insert mode" and then type `:TOhtml` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will result is having a split window in terminal, half is your R code and the other half id your new HTML code.
5. For saving the files, type `:x` along with <kbd>Enter</kbd> button from keyboard twice to save both files (your R file will be unchanged if you have not typed anything extra in it and your HTML file will be created with the same name near your R code)
6. Now open it with your favorite browser (in my case Vivaldi) and do what ever you want (in my case converting the whole HTML into PNG)

Answer (score 2):

Best way:
download https://github.com/jaredpetersen/codeprinter and paste in the r code. then choose syntax highlighting Xcode

Comment: then you got exactly the colors like in rstudio

Comment: @jzadra
I checked it again and it still works for me

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was expecting it to change in the text box where code is pasted when I selected XCode.  I see that it does not, but it does change when going to print.

Comment: @jzadra
Yes, this is a strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

For those using a Mac (and thus without access to Notepad++) cutting and pasting into Xcode and printing from there will also work.

As with Ron Jensen's earlier comment, this isn't an R Studio solution, but in the interests of "just getting it to work", I hope this helps someone.